# Function Return But No Value

Tags: python, function, return

I have a function defined which includes a return statement but no value is handed back.  My code is as follows:

```
def seed(addy):

    # urllib2 stuff is here

    seed_result = re.search('<td>Results 1 - \d+ of (\d+)',seed_query)  # searches for '<td>Results 1 - x of y', captures 'y'
    seed_result = seed_result.group(1)  # this is 'y' from above

    # there's a call to a different function here which works properly    
    # other stuff going on here pertaining to addy but seed_result still has my string

    # now I want to return the seed_result string...
    return seed_result

# ... some code outside of the seed function, then I call seed...

seed(addy)
print "Result is %s" % seed_result
```

I have tried this with and without defining seed_result outside of the function to "initialize" it but this has no impact on the outcome which is that my print statement at the end yields "Result is " - there's no seed_result.  I have also wrapped seed_result in parenthesis in the return statement though I believe how I have it is correct.  The parens didn't make a difference.

A set up a very basic, yet similar, function in the Python shell and called it as I do here but that works.  Not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks for the feedback and guidance.

Comment: Tried to do a print statement to call the function which resulted in "Result is None".  *scratching head*

Comment: The reason that it works in the Python shell is that the shell prints out the result of any expression evaluated.  To get hold of it in your program, you have to assign it to some variable, as Jon Skeet said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways of solving this:

First, the **proper**, **obvious**, and **easy** way is actually using the `return`ed value:

```
seedresult = seed(addy)
```

Or you use a global variable (**bad style - avoid at any cost**):

```
seedresult = None

def seed(addy):
    global seedresult
    ...
```

Comment: The global variable advice is harmful; it's worse than bad style imho.  Your fist solution is the correct one.

Comment: Indeed, I've emphasized this in the post now.

Comment: I can certainly see pros and cons to using global so I will have to educate myself further offline.  Thanks a bunch to all of you.

Comment: Using `global` is IMHO okay, when it is within a module and it is used for accessing a truly shared object, such as a cache. The whole point of a cache can be to share it across instances.

Comment: But in this case it obscures the issue, which is returning and using a value from a function.  In this case there are no pros to using the global approach.

Answer (score 9):

You're not *using* the return value (e.g. assigning it to a variable). Try this:

```
result = seed(addy)
print "Result is %s" % result
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>This is caused by `None` being assigned to `seed_result` during the execution of your function.</strike>

As Jon Skeet identified, you are doing nothing with the return value of your function. You should also address the issues below, though.

In particular, you are doing nothing with the parameter `addy`, and searching a global variable `seed_query`. I imagine the behaviour you are seeing is a result of that.

Comment: Addy is actually being used in code that was snipped from the sample for brevity.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @BitBucket: Only snip for brevity if you know what you're doing.

Comment: I snipped code that was not relevant to my problem and that was working - this was noted in my original post.

Comment: @BitBucket: You snipped to the point of making your code confusing, not to mention if you don't know how variables work (the root of your problem), you don't have much credibility as to your ability to judge which code is and is not relevant.

Comment: @Mercin: You were the only one that seemed to be confused by my post - clearly because you did not read (I posted that addy was used).  I certainly knew enough to cut the cruff to get concise assistance - this effort was a success.  Take care.